# Polyparse library cannot be installed

Tags: haskell, error-handling

I'm having a trouble on installing Polyparse library (Haskell library) 
And i do not know how to solve it ....
May someone helps me,please ?

This is the error output :

```
D-MacBook-Pro:polyparse-1.9 d$ cabal install polyparse.cabal
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring polyparse-1.9...
Failed to install polyparse-1.9
Last 10 lines of the build log ( /Users/d/.cabal/logs/polyparse-1.9.log ):
cabal: /Users/d/.cabal/logs/polyparse-1.9.log: does not exist
```

**The problem now ...**

```
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: bpsat-0.1.0 (user goal)
trying: smt-lib-0.0.3/installed-d94... (dependency of bpsat-0.1.0)
next goal: polyparse (dependency of smt-lib-0.0.3/installed-d94...)
rejecting: polyparse-1.9/installed-42c... (conflict: polyparse =>
text==1.1.1.2/installed-cb1..., bpsat => text==0.11.*)
rejecting: polyparse-1.9, 1.8, 1.7, 1.6, 1.5, 1.4.1, 1.4, 1.3, 1.2, 1.1, 1.0
(conflict: smt-lib => polyparse==1.9/installed-42c...)
Dependency tree exhaustively searched.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried to install polyparse on my Ubuntu machine, and it worked....

Here is how I usually fix installation problems.

```
$ cabal update

$ cabal unpack polyparse

$ cd polyparse-*

$ cabal configure
```

Now look for errors....  Dependency errors usually appear at this point.  They come in two forms- Either 1). for some reason another cabal package is missing, and you can usually install it by doing the appropriate `cabal install <packageName>` (yes, cabal was supposed to do this for you, but I find it sometimes doesn't), or 2). A system c-library is missing, and you will have install that.  Either way, the message should make it clear.  If it doesn't, append the message to your question and we can help.

```
$ cabal build
```

Again, look for errors.  Build errors often appear here, and usually indicate a bug in the package.  Since the install just worked for me, this is less likely, but I've seen stuff that installs on one OS and breaks on another.  Again, you can put the message here and we can help.

```
$ cabal install
```

If this works, the package should be installed.

---

update

It looks like the dependency smt-lib isn't installing....  Try to repeat the steps above on that lib, and repost the results.

---

Update 2-

The new error message looks to be telling me there is a conflict in the Text lib,  bpsat needs one version and polyparse needs another.  I am not sure why this is happening, as I mentioned, for me things worked.  Sometimes things in ~/.cabal get messed up, and you might want to try to delete (well, actually, move it in case you decide you need it) everything in .cabal *except* ~/.cabal/bin/.  Then try again.  You will probably have to reinstall other libs, but this might solve the problem.

Comment: It worked ! But i had a problem which i repost my own topic, can you help me ?

Comment: I've added more info.

Comment: Didn't do anything :/

Comment: @Damiii- Do you mean that smt-lib didn't install?  If so, show the error.  Or do you mean that it did install, but polyparse still didn't install.  If so, show the new error, I doubt that the new error message would be that smt-lib is missing after it was installed, but perhaps something else is missing.

Comment: (sorry to answer only right now ... But i had so much to do these days ...)

Comment: I think it's the same error as i mentioned upstairs.

Comment: I can't install my smt-lib

Comment: I must say, i installed Mint on my Mac OS (Virtual Machine) and it worked perfectly ! Maybe it's an issue from Mac OS ? Or the libraries aren't working on Mac OS. What do you think ?

Comment: Currently I think that your data in ~/.cabal might be in a confused state, but I have seen stuff install in Linux but not Mac before, so who knows.